# Selenium Chromedriver error - receiver class does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract createArgs()

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open chrome driver using selenium but it is giving me this error. This is the first project that this error is popping up for me as I've had a different project that used selenium and it worked fine. I believe the error may be because of my pom.xml file. I am unsure if I'm missing anything or if it is the order of dependencies I have. Here is my code: `static SortedMap<String,String> QuebecConsolidatedStatutesAndPDFs = new TreeMap<String,String>();

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\WorkSpace\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/chapters?corpus=statutes&selection=all");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    List<WebElement> QuebecConsolidatedStatutes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'clickable')]"));
    
    String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (int i=0; i<QuebecConsolidatedStatutes.size(); i++){
        String opentabs = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
        

        QuebecConsolidatedStatutes.get(i).sendKeys(opentabs);
    
    }

    int i=QuebecConsolidatedStatutes.size()-1; 
        Set<String> tabs = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String child:tabs){
            if (!parent.equalsIgnoreCase(child)){
                driver.close();
                driver.switchTo().window(child);
                String StatuteName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form']/div[2]/div[1]/h3/text()")).getText();
                String pagePdfUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='renditionPdf']")).getAttribute("href");
                if (i!=0){
                    QuebecConsolidatedStatutesAndPDFs.put(StatuteName, pagePdfUrl);
                    i-=1;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
                
        }
        System.out.println(QuebecConsolidatedStatutesAndPDFs);
}
```

}`The error is the following:`cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java.exe" @C:\Users\Nasse\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_8rv48yyid2l2bl8g8rlqdo6bn.argfile com.example.App "
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract createArgs()Ljava/util/List; of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:441)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
at com.example.App.main(App.java:23)`

Comment: Add your code snippet.

Comment: Just added it. Thanks